# Sqlservice model.update() does not update the orm object but sessio.query().update() does

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlservice` orm which is essentially another wrapper over `sqlalchemy`. I am trying to update an object via three methods but one works and other two does not

When I try below method it works and the row is updated in the database

```
model_obj = MyModel(col1="val1", col2="val2")
try:
    db.session.add(model_obj)
    db.session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    db.session.rollback()
    db.session.query(MyModel).filter_by(col=model_obj.col).update({"col2":"val"})
    db.session.commit()
```

However when I do the following, the operation goes through without any errors/warnings but db is not updated.

```
model_obj = MyModel(col1="val1", col2="val2")
try:
    db.session.add(model_obj)
    db.session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    db.session.rollback()
    model_obj.col2 = "val3"    # or model_obj.update({{"col2":"val"}})
    db.session.commit()
```

Am i missing something obvious here ?

Comment: `model_obj` does not yet exist in the DB as far as SQLA knows, you just created it (instead of fetching it).

Comment: So does that mean the only way to do this is how I am doing it currently i.e first fetching it and then updating it ?

Comment: `db.session.query(MyModel)...update({"col2":"val"})` does not fetch first and then update, but emits an `UPDATE` directly.

Answer (score 0):

After a `commit` the session is cleared. So `model_obj` isn't bound to the session anymore. When using `query` to update the model object it's added to the session again so `commit` adds it to the database.

So after the rollback in your example the session doesn't have any reference to `model_obj`. If you want to use this to update an existing database entry you can use [`merge`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge) instead of `add`. Which does the following:

> examines the primary key attributes of the source instance, and attempts to reconcile it with an instance of the same primary key in the session. If not found locally, it attempts to load the object from the database based on primary key, and if none can be located, creates a new instance.

This means that your object definition needs to contain the primary key of the object that you want to update! (Which is probably the case as the insert fails with an `IntegrityError`.

```py
model_obj = MyModel(col1="val1", col2="val2")
try:
    db.session.add(model_obj)
    db.session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    db.session.rollback()
    model_obj.col2 = "val3"    # or model_obj.update({{"col2":"val"}})
    db.session.merge(model_obj)
    db.session.commit()
```

Effectively this means that (if you want to add a new object if it doesn't exist or update an existing database entry) you can also safely write the following (if you want to keep the updated values the same).

```py
model_obj = MyModel(col1="val1", col2="val2")
db.session.merge(model_obj)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: This code does not work as expected since merge expects an existing instance, which we have to fetch from db, so before the `db.session.merge(model_obj)` we have to load the object from db like `MyModel.filter_by(filter)`. If we skip this step and simply do `db.session.merge(my_obj)` we will still end up in the same `IntegrityError`. And i noticed if we load the object anyhow then we can even use `db.session.add(model_obj)` and it works just fine.

Comment: If you read the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge) that's not the case. Except that in your created instance one of the values needs to be the primary key. If it fails due to a unique constraint this doesn't work. How does your table definition look?